# Not able to get objectId in query.containedIn query with parse?

Tags: javascript, object, parse-platform

I am using parse.com as my back end.

I am using containedIn query to retrieve multiple user rows from parse "User" table.
My problem is that I am not able to get user's object Id in the success block

following is my code:

```
     r_userIdList= ['PzpdRdKTVZ','PoJdRdKTVU','fvdRdKTVX'];
     var query = new Parse.Query("_User");
             query.containedIn("objectId", r_userIdList); // returns multiple rows
             query.find({
                          success: function(r_uobject) {

                            var userObjId ,fName,lName,full_Name="Unknown User";
                          for(var i =0; i<r_uobject.length;i++){


                            var r_obj = r_uobject[i];
                            uID = r_obj.get('objectId');//not working
                            var u = uID.id;//not working

                            fName = r_obj.get('firstName'); 
                            lName = r_obj.get('lastName');
                            full_Name = firstName+' '+lastName;
                           r_userIdList[u].fullName = full_Name; //not working

                           }
                     }
               });
```

Once I enter in the success block, I am unable to identify that which user's data has been retrieved.
Actually I need user's ObjectId because I have array called r_userIdList in which I need to store the firstName and LastName of user as Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs can usually be accessed with `.id` - in your case `r_obj.id`. Your `uID.id` won't work as `uID` is itself going to be undefined.

You also need to check that you are getting any results back at all: does `r_userIdList` have a length?